# How do I address the "this" object confusion in my code

Tags: javascript

This code is from the book *Functional JavaScript*, page 32:

```
var a = {name: "a", fun: function(){ console.log(this);}};
a.fun();

var bfun = function(){ console.log(this);};
var b = {name: "b", fun: bfun};
b.fun();
```

As per the book, `b.fun()` should print either the global object or something else, however, in my case it's printing the object `b`.

Is this a typo in the book or am I missing something here?

Comment: `this` refers to the current context. In this code, `this` will refer to the object `b` when `b.fun()` is called. Even though the function is declared outside of `b`, it is called from `b`.

Comment: the bfun gets called from var b. So it should print the object b.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an error in the book and is corrected in the [errata](http://www.oreilly.com/catalog/errata.csp?isbn=0636920028857):

> The book claims that the following code will result in  a global
>   object:
>
> ```
> var bFunc = function () { return this }; 
> var b = {name: "b", fun: bFunc};
> b.fun();
> //=> some global object, probably Window
> ```
>
> This is incorrect. In fact, b.fun()  returns the object stored in the
>   variable b. The semantics of this is such that this is set  when the
>   function is invoked, not when the function is defined. If the function
>   is called using either b.fun() or b'fun', this is set to b.
>
> Note from the Author or Editor: This is definitely misleading.  A more
>   appropriate snippet would be:
>
> ```
> var bObj = {name: "b", fun: function(){ return this }};
> bObj.fun();
> //=> {name: "b", fun: function (){ return this }}
>
> var bFunc = bObj.fun;
> bFunc();
> //=> some global object, probably Window
> ```
>
> The explanation text would then read as follows:
>
> Well, this might be surprising. You see, when a function is called
>   within the context of an object, its this reference points to the
>   object itself. However, when I later bound bFunc to the field
>   bObj.fun, its reference was changed to the global object when called.
>   In most programming languages offering...

Answer (score 0):

```
bfun(); // logs "Window" (or global object)
b.fun(); // logs "b"
```

The word `this` always refers to the object running the function.

Answer (score -1):

Of course, it's the global window obejct. Try to consider the runtime state. The scope is who call the function, not expression.

The following code will help you out:

```
var a = {name: "a", fun: function(){ console.log(this);}};
  a.fun();

  var bfun = function(){ console.log(this);};
  var b = new Function();
      b.name="b";
      b.fun=bfun;
  b.fun();
```